Telegram Web Apps. Не работает input file multiple на Андроиде
Не работает аттрибут multiple тега <input type="file">.
В Telegram Desktop все корректно, в консоли отображает все выбранные файлы:

При отладке в Telegram на телефоне (проверяю на Xiaomi Poco X3) @change не реагирует на выбор нескольких файлов. При выборе одного файла он отображается. Если 1 файл уже выбран - при выборе нескольких файлов @change срабатывает и в консоле показывает что файлы не выбраны:

Код:
<input type="file" @change="handleFileChange" multiple/>

handleFileChange(e: Event) {
      const target = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
      const files = target.files;
      console.log(files);
}

Так же существует проблема с аттрибутом accept="image/*". Когда он установлен, на этом же телефоне не могу выбрать даже 1 файл. После выбора @change не срабатывает, и почему-то открывается мобильная клавиатура, которая закрывается только по мобильной кнопке "Назад"
